# Need to add some CSS to a <p> that contains "Save" buttons, What would the selector look like?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have some html:

```
<p>
        <button type="submit" name="btn" value="Save">Save</button>
        <button type="submit" name="btn" value="Cancel">Cancel</button>
</p>
```

I would like to create a CSS selector that matches all "p" tags that contain the above button(s) so that I can add a :

```
padding-top:20px;
```

to it.

It would also be interesting to see if one can add this style to another parent like "div".

I guess one would just do something like:

```
p button, div button {}
```

The above applies the style to the button tag whereas I wish to add it to the "div" or "p" tag.

Thoughts??

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Put a class on the `<p>`, select by class, and move on

Comment: You cannot select in css based on the child elements, you will need to use JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: If you wanted to do this with jQuery.. `$('p:has(button[value="Save"])').css("background","red");` [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/wp95R/)

Comment: Thank you for all of your comments. Very helpful. Did not know it could not be done as standard, but there is a workaround in JQuery.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery answer:

```
$('p:has(button[value="Save"])').addClass('containsButtons');
```

Comment: I actually went with the Class suggestion in the end as I wanted to keep it in CSS, but thank you anyway.